# replace() error in MAGE function in R's iglu package for glucose analysis

Tags: r, replace, cgm

I'm trying to use the `all_metrics()` function of the [**iglu** package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/iglu/index.html) in R. The function always throws an error when calling the `mage_ma_single()` function, which itself gets called by the `mage()` function. **Here's the [package's function's source code which leads to an error](https://github.com/irinagain/iglu/blob/master/R/mage_ma_single.R), see lines 58 to 64.**

Here's the error I'm getting:

> Error: Problem with `mutate()` column `MA_Long`.
> ℹ `MA_Long = replace(MA_Long, 1:long_ma, MA_Long[long_ma])`.
> ℹ `MA_Long` must be size 5 or 1, not 23.

Here's some sample data with which I can reproduce the error:

```
structure(list(id = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1), time = structure(c(1611228720, 1611229080, 1611247620, 1611249960, 1611263940), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), gl = c(97L, 90L, 89L, 96L, 87L)), row.names = c(NA, 5L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: The problem is `long_ma` has default value as 23, we cannot change it. Since your data does not have 23 rows it returns an error.

Comment: Does that mean I need to have at least 23 observations per ID? Or could I also go into the source code of the function and set these values to 0?

Comment: I actually tried that with `iglu::all_metrics(df[sample(5, 23, replace = TRUE), ])` but it returned another error. I haven't used that package/function so I don't know how is that supposed to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out there needed to be at least 23 observations per ID in order for all_metrics() (and mage_ma_single()) to run successfully. I've mailed the package's author, Irina Gaynanova, and she'll look into providing a fix soon.